# Comparing 2 string arrays

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections

I want to **compare 2 string arrays**  in the fastest way.
I got something like below.
Will that  be the right way to do. Or is there a better way to do

```
            bool matching=false;
            //say templateArr is the template array and dataArr as array to be compared
            string[] templateArr = {"Dictionary_type","Translation_EN" };
            string[] dataArr = { "Dictionary_type", "Translation_EN" };

            if (templateArr.Union(dataArr).Distinct().Count() == templateArr.Count())
                matching = true;
```

Comment: When you say **compare** you mean that they must have the same strings? With your current example, I'd say that they are equal. But, if `dataArr` had one more (say, "Test"), what should be the result?

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to clarify what you mean by comparing them. Do you want to know if they both contain a certain element? If they have the same amount of entries?

Comment: What if they have the same elements, but are in different order?  e.g. is {"Foo", "Bar"} equivalent to {"Bar", "Foo"}?

Comment: I think this is very good method, it's very easy to go~

Comment: different order is fine .but the array elements must be equal

Comment: Just a note here because we're all big on Linq. If you need 'fastest' then nothing will beat an old fashioned loop and basic comparisons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test for collection equality, you can use [`Enumerable.SequenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) as follows.

```
using System.Linq;

bool AreEqual()
{
    string[] templateArr = { "Dictionary_type", "Translation_EN" };
    string[] dataArr = { "Dictionary_type", "Translation_EN" };

    return templateArr.SequenceEquals(dataArr);
}
```

If you want to test for collection equivalence (order of elements does not matter), then you can use [set-equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx) as follows.

```
bool AreEquivalent()
{
    string[] templateArr = { "Dictionary_type", "Translation_EN" };
    string[] dataArr = { "Dictionary_type", "Translation_EN" };

    return new HashSet<string>(templateArr).SetEquals(dataArr);
}
```

Both cases are implemented in linear time, as per the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Way better than mine, +1. But they would be `bool` rather than `void`, right?

Comment: in void method, we can't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a `union` and then counting the total elements with only one of them. `Union` removes the repetition, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach, because it's a relatively expensive operation.

Look at this alternative:

```
        string[] templateArr = { "Dictionary_type", "Translation_EN" };
        string[] dataArr = { "Dictionary_type", "Translation_EN" };

        bool matching = templateArr.Length == dataArr.Length ? !templateArr.Any<string>(x => !dataArr.Contains(x)) : false;
```

Comment: Not very performant for large arrays - essentially a nested loop. Then  again, it might perform well for small arrays.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I see, but since we are working with **arrays**, would you have a better suggestion? Feedbacks will be appreciated.

Comment: Yup, sorting the arrays beforehand or putting them in a HashSet could be justified for larger arrays.

Comment: I prefer to add this additional condition , if (templateArr.Length != dataArr.Length) matching=false;                                            yes that looks bit expensive

Comment: @sankaras this condition is already there, see the ternary operator.

Comment: @sankaras Anyway, Steve's solution is way better, forget mine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they should be considered unequal if they have same elements but in different order, you can just use the [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
if (templateArr.SequenceEqual(dataArr))
    matching = true;
```

If you want to ignore the order, sort the arrays first:

```
if (templateArr.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(dataArr.OrderBy(x => x)))
    matching = true;
```

And if you want to also ignore duplicates:

```
if (templateArr.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(dataArr.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x)))
    matching = true;
```

Or (more concise, and likely to be faster):

```
if (new HashSet<string>(templateArr).SetEquals(dataArr))
    matching = true;
```

---

BTW, your code is incorrect - it will conclude the arrays match in this case:

```
string[] templateArr = { "Dictionary_type", "Translation_EN", "abc" };
string[] dataArr = { "Translation_EN", "Dictionary_type", "Translation_EN" };

if (templateArr.Union(dataArr).Distinct().Count() == templateArr.Count())
    matching = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the previous comments - the question is slightly ambigous as you don't clarify what constitutes to equivalent arrays, but assuming that you treat arrays as equavalent if they contain the same number of identical strings (in any order), before I would resort to the HashSet(array1).SetEquals(array2);

I would try to determine whether the arrays are equal using the following simple technique:

1. compare the length, if the lengths are different - return false
   sort arrays, set counter to 0
2. Compare array[0] elements - if different return false
3. Repeat the procedure for each next one, using indexing, not foreach
4. Return true

With this approach for large arrays - you are likely to find difference instead of actually loading arrays in memory or rely on hashsetting the entire arrays therefore gaining more efficient performance/memory consumption